# Is inlining function to solve multi definition a well-defined thing?

Tags: c++, c++11, inline

I am building a templated-header-only C++11 library. As I have read, I should define my member functions as `inline` in order to guarantee that multi existence of definition in the translation unit will not occur.

Is this a well-defined use of the `inline` keyword? I used to think that `inline` is performance-related thing. I am in doubt that by using `inline` for this purpose is like opening a backdoor. Any drawbacks for using it? any other solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Joachim's question answers the main question about the semantics of inline, but the OP also asks about drawbacks of using inline. The usual trade-off when performing inlining is between code size and speed. We have two cases:

1. The function is actually inlined. In this case, the body is copied all over increasing the code size of the final program. This may also include a performance penalty because it becomes harder to cache the program code in the processor cache.
2. The function is not inlined. I am assuming an inline function with external linkage. In this case, the linker will remove all copies but one to ensure that the function's address is unique in the whole program. This process can slow down your build process. On msvc <= 2010, this used to be a major issue  because the linker was single threaded and dead slow.
3. Inline functions have to be parsed and compiled in every compilation unit they are used. This can slow down the build process.

A better approach might be to use whole-program optimization where the compiler can optimize across compilation units. All major compilers support this.

Answer (score 7):

If you read e.g. [this `inline` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline) you will see a list of properties for functions with external linkage, and the second point says:

> It has the same address in every translation unit.

This means that declaring a function as `inline` will lead to only one instance of that function existing across all [*translation units*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_%28programming%29) (i.e. all object files generated from the source files).

Since only one instance of the function exist, there won't be any multiple definition errors.

Comment: Thnaks. So, can I infer from your answer is this use is perfectly fine and acceptable with no other solution?

Comment: Does C++11,14 provides a way to separate template declaration from it's definition ?

Comment: You mean rather than writing them in the same .h file ? However, you may ask in separate question

Comment: Doesn't it mean that the function will NOT actually be inlined?

Comment: @AngelusMortis Depends on what you want to do. In general, the definition must be available when instantiating the template. You can put it in different files and #include them when needed, you can forward-declare a template function etc. C++11 also introduced extern templates for explicit definitions.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe It means the function may be inlined. It is a hint for the compiler, but the ultimate decision is made by the compiler and not by the programmer. Compilers are free to generate code that has the same semantics (on the abstract machine defined by the C++ standard), but they can emit code very different from what the programmer had in mind.

Comment: @Jens, I am aware of that. A function that has been inlined has no address, the way I see it. And the standard says that an `inline` function not only has an address, but this address is the same for all translation units, as if it was a normal function. That makes no sense to me.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe There's always the actual definition of the function, it will always be generated. Then *if* the compiler decides to actually inline the function, it creates a *copy* inline. But the non-inlined definition will still be there.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: "There's always the actual definition of the function" - except that if nobody takes its address, it may not exist.

Comment: @MartinBonner Of course, if it's not called (or its "address taken") then it might be optimized away. But if there's one non-inlined call, or someone gets a pointer to the function, or otherwise store a reference to the function, it must exist as a non-inlined copy.

Answer (score 3):

As far as the standard is concerned, the *only* significance of the `inline` keyword is to prevent errors from multiple definitions.

Once you have the function defined in multiple translation units, compilers *may* include a copy of the function in each translation unit (although they have to ensure that taking the address of the function gives a single, unique, result), and they *may* decide to expand the function at every call site (or they may not).

If you want a header-only library, marking the members as `inline` (either with the keyword, or by defining them in the body of the class) is mandatory.  The advantage of a header only library is that it is easy to use, the disadvantage is it can take longer to compile clients, and more may have to be recompiled when you change it.